# Javascript function doesn't break on return?

Tags: javascript, loops, return, break

I know you are supposed to be able to break out of an each statement by returning, which is what I'm trying to do, but I must be doing something wrong and it seems so simple I can't find it.

I have code like this

```
function create() {
  var test = hasThing();
  if (test) {
    $('#myForm').submit();
  } else {
    alert('you suck!')
  }
}

function hasThing() {
  $('.selects').each(function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

I have set breakpoints on "return true;" and hit it but var test is always false because for some reason the .each() loop continues and the hasThing() function continues. I've tried switching things around so that I return false in the .each() just in case for some reason that mattered but it didn't change anything.

I don't get it. Seems counter to how the documentation says it should work.

Comment: To break `.each` you **have** to return `false`, and returning from inside the `each` loop does not return from the outer function.

Comment: `Seems counter to how the documentation says it should work.` - the documentation says "You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false". How is the behavior not inline with the docs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `return true;` statement returns from the anonymous function given to `each`. The `return false;` line is always executed which explains why `var test` is always false.

Change your code to

```
function hasThing() {
  var hasThing = false;
  $('.selects').each(function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      hasThing = true;
      return false; // breaks the $.each, but does not return from hasThing()
    }
  });
  return hasThing;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains my mistake very well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.some()` to check if any of the selects have a selected value

```
function hasThing() {
    return $('select').toArray().some(function(el) {
        return el.value != "";
    })
}
```

```js
function create() {

    var test = hasThing();

    if (test) {
        alert('at least one select was changed');
        //$('#myForm').submit();
    } else {
        alert('you suck!');
    }
}

function hasThing() {
 return $('select').toArray().some(function(el) {
     return el.value != "";
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select at least one option !</p>
<form id="myForm">
    <select class="selects">
        <option value="">blank</option>
        <option value="2">option1</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="selects">
        <option value="">blank</option>
        <option value="2">option1</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="button" onclick="create()" value="submit" />
    
</form>
```

Comment: Much easier to read (and, thus, maintain), though potentially much less efficient as the other suggestion supports "short-circuiting". Depends on how complex the `this.value =` logic actually is and how many elements are matched. Wish vanilla jQuery had a ".any()" function.

Comment: @JDB - It does, `Array.some`, but then the values would have to be mapped to an array, it's not really any more efficient, using a filter shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Doh. That would save you, on average, half the computation cycles (and time) and would not be particularly more difficult to implement.

Comment: @JDB - I don't see how, it would look something like -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lxg4k/1/**

Comment: ... `[].some.call($('.selects'), function(e) { return !!e.value; })` ??  (or with `$.trim()` of course)

Comment: @Pointy - Ah, using the argument like that would work !

Comment: What's wrong with `$('.selects').get().some(function(){ return this.value != '' })`?

Comment: @JDB yea that'd work too - I didn't think of it because I have a superstitious fear of jQuery `.get()` for reasons I wish I could figure out (@JDB you'd need to operate on the parameter instead of `this` as in my edit however)

Comment: @JDB - that works too, but `get()` is really just calling `slice` and it still iterates. For efficience you'll never notice the difference between any of these, unless you have a billion elements

Comment: @Pointy - According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), `this` and the parameter should be the same reference. Perhaps I misunderstood something though.

Comment: @Pointy - I have that same fear, and I usually always use `$.map`, `$.each` etc. just to not have to add a `get()` at the end, as it's scary as hell, but I'm starting to get over it.

Comment: @adeneo - Yes, again depending on the actual complexity of the `this.value =` test. If there's much more to it, then executing this function may result in a perceivable difference. As stated, though, I don't think the difference would be noticeable. A short-circuiting `.any()` function would be an awesome addition to jQuery... I don't know much about Sizzle, though, so I have no idea if that'd actually be feasible.